# Find and remove duplicate IDs and replace

Tags: excel, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

I have very basic user Excel knowledge. I have a spreadsheet where I keep track of reloading data. Each load I enter gets a unique load number that is calculated automatically with a formula, based on the caliber name and an incrementally increasing number. As of now, every load I enter gets a number, even if it's been repeated before. Popular loads that I repeat often are all the same except for the date and numbers of rounds made but currently will have different load numbers. Is there a way to skips these repeated loads and assign it the previous load number or not assign a load number at all, with a formula instead of manually?

I know this is asking for a great deal but I'd greatly appreciate any help! I'm certainly open to suggestions if this isn't even the best way to go about this.

Sample workbook at:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5y1ufxjiosmnap/My%20Reloading%20Data%20-%20Sample.xlsx?dl=0

Here's what I've tried so far:

In column Q2, combine all the criteria.

```
=C17&E17&F17&G17&H17&L17&M17&N17&P17
```

In column R2 look for duplicates.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($Q$2:$Q17, $Q17)>1, "Duplicate", "")
```

D2 is the Load # column.

```
=IF(R17="Duplicate","",(TEXT(C17,0)&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C17,C17),"000")))
```

This will skip the duplicate loads and not give them a load # leaving the cell blank. I'd love to find and match what that load # should be and insert it. Also, when the sequential numbering resumes it acts as if it's counted the duplicate row. For instance D2 might look like:

```
9mm-001
9mm-002
```

(Skipped for duplicate and left blank, but would like it to find, match, and insert the duplicate load #)

```
9mm-004 (I'd like to to be 9mm-003)
```

Comment: Ever heard of the 'Purple Peril'? Absolutely magical trout fly for the late spring/early summer months.

Comment: That's a traditional steelhead fly, yes?  Never tried it.  I'll check it out.

Comment: (1) I understand that 'helper' columns make logic more transparent but once the logic is established, newer functions like COUNTIFS can eliminate the 'helper' columns. (2) Why was it necessary to post a macro-enabled workbook. Some volunteers may be hesitant to download an xlsm while xlsx wouldn't be a problem. (3) Yes, that fly is good for late Jan glacial fed streams as well (4) What have you got against 0.40 S&W?

Comment: Sorry, for the sample I made a copy of my reloading workbook which is macro enabled and didn't catch it.  I'll change that.  Why shoot .40 S&W when there's 10mm?!

Comment: I prefer the P226 navy with a Hogue grip to the P220.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a `VLOOKUP` formula or a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`.

`VLOOKUP`  (Vertical Lookup) looks for a match in another cell and returns a value from an offset column. A non match, if you use FALSE as the last parameter, returns a #N/A error.

So, in D20 (for example) you could, using column Q as your determinant, use the following, assuming you had a copy of D in column R:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Q20,Q$1:R19,2,FALSE),[value for newly found loadno])
```

What this formula does is calculates a `VLOOKUP` - if that doesn't find a record, calculate a new value. The VLOOKUP will look at the concatenated key in the current row Q column, search through all previous columns (note it is anchored at row 1, but not anchored for the bottom of the range so you can copy the formula), it uses the column 2 (Q is column 1, so R is column 2) for the result, and demands an exact match (FALSE). If it doesn't find one, return NA and let the second half of the `IFERROR` take over.

See how you go with this.

The `MATCH` `INDEX` may work better because you won't need the additional R column due to `VLOOKUP` only being able to look to the right of the key.

Here is an `INDEX` and `MATCH` solution - slightly harder to understand, but a more flexible solution.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D19,MATCH(Q20,Q$1:Q19,0)),[value for newly found load number])
```

I prefer this.

The outer function says return the nth value in the list. The inner `MATCH` function says find this value (Q20) in this list (Q1:Q19). The 0 as the third parameter of the `MATCH` function says the match has to be exact.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I got both to work.  Neither worked at first but I figured it out.  
 With VLOOKUP the table-array has to have as many columns as the col_index_num.  The missing R in IFERROR through me off for a minute.  That's seems a cleaner solution.

Comment: It's not a huge issue but what about keeping my numbers sequential even when rows are skipped due to duplicates?  My formula counts off the row number.  Here what's I have in D2: `=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D2,MATCH(Q2,Q$1:Q1,0)),(TEXT(C2,0)&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2),"000")))`

Comment: @Flyfishermanmike, please mark this answer as solved (the ticker below the upvote of this answer). It shows that this question is answered and gives credit to the person who answered. Thanks!

Comment: Will do.  I'll start a new question for my other question.